# I'm trying to convert this for loop into a function

Tags: excel, vba

My problem is the fact that I don't know what functions (in C++) or methods (in Java) are called in VBA.

They both exist and so I have looked up subs? Which I think are the parallel, but they don't return anything from what I understand.

I don't have any formal training in VBA, so I'm kind of bad at this. I want to create a function (or method or sub) that does what this for loop is doing:

```
useInput = titles.Text
useRec = rec.Text
lastRow = 1

For Each rngCell In rngData.Columns(1).Cells 'Traverse each row in Spreadsheet
If useInput = rngCell.Value And LCase(useRec) = LCase(Cells(lastRow, 2)) Then 'If what the user input into the textbox matches a value in the spreadsheet
    bothExist = True 'Set this to true, because both exist

    otherUserForm.Show 'Call another userform created

    titles = "" 'Set entries to null
    rec = ""
    Exit For 'Exit the for loop
    End If
    lastRow = lastRow + 1 'Counter
Next rngCell
```

So the whole point of the loop is to just traverse a spreadsheet and find the last row to enter information, however find if the titles and rec are pre existing, then it does what is shown.

My question is, what do I need to create so it returns, "lastRow?" Because I need whatever that number is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions in VBA are just that: functions. :-) The `return` syntax is strange, though, if you're used to Java or C/C++ (it's more old-style Pascal).

```
Public Function GetLastRow()
   `Logic to determine last row here
   GetLastRow = lastRow    ` Assignment to function name sets return value
End Function
```

Comment: When I looked up functions, it seemed as though the ones you declare as functions can only be called within excel. I want to call this function inside an event? So where do I put this, "Function?" Is it inside a module?

Comment: Yes, you put it in a module, and then add a reference to that module in your workbook. It seems you need to Google for a [VBA tutorial](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s161/online-excel-vba-training.htm) to get you started. :-) Use the `Developer` tab in the ribbon, click the `Visual Basic` button, `Insert->Module` menu, then `Insert->Procedure`. You can then decide whether it's private or public and a procedure or function, and name it. The VBA IDE will create the stub for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Function myFunctionName()
    ' do stuff
    myFunctionName = "hello world"
End Function
```

You assign a return value to a function by assigning it to the name of the function. You can call it like this:

```
Sub myTest()
theReply = myFunctionName()
msgBox "the function returned " & theReply
End Sub
```

Functions return values, subs don't.